# Running two maven plugins using a single command

Tags: maven, plugins, jenkins, soapui

I have two dependencies in my POM:one for the soapui maven plugin and one for my custom plugin. So I want to be able to access the files generated by the first plugin to create a report using the second plugin. I need these two plugins to be run one after the other using a single command so that I will be able to configure it in Jenkins.Currently I am able to run it but if the build fails while running the first plugin then the second plugin is not invoked. I want it to run the second plugin irrespective of the build result of the first plugin.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a post-build-step "run maven goal" with your custom goal and configure it to run every time - no matter what the first build produced.